# regex to find substring and then split based on delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a file in which there are strings of the form

```
key=v1,v2,v3,...,vn;
```

contained with in a larger string. I know how to do this with standard python string operators, but I'd like to do with with regex. I can extract the substring trivially with

```
s = "key=v1,v2,v3,v4,v5;"
re.findall(key=(.*?)\;',s)
```

which returns

```
['v1,v2,v3,v4,v5']
```

and I can split the returned substring separately with:

```
s = "v1,v2,v3,v4,v5"
re.findall(r'(.+?)(?:,|$)', s)
```

which returns

```
['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5']
```

but can't figure out how to combine them into one regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[^,=]+?(?=,|;)
```

That is - repeat non-comma, non-equals characters, until lookahead matches a comma or semicolon.

https://regex101.com/r/4B3cP0/1

```
s = "key=v1,v2,v3,v4,v5;"
result = re.findall(r'[^,=]+?(?=,|;)', s)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! What if s = "key1=v1,v2,v3; key2=v3,v4,v5; key3=v6,v7,v8;" and I want to extract just v3,v4,v5?

Comment: If you use the `regex` module instead of `re`, you can use `\G` to match the position at the end of the previous match, allowing you to get v3, v4, and v5 with `(?:\G,|key2=)\K[^,; ]+`